# NAS shares cannot be accessed by name in a domain

Tags: domain, samba, synology, shares

I have a NAS (Synology DS411, DSM 4.3) that was configured to be joined to an AD domain. Privileges were appropriately set on the shares and everything was fine.

I (foolishly) changed the name of the device on the network. This action removed the device from the domain. I then set to join it to the domain again (successfully).

Now:

- I cannot access the shared folders with the network name via Windows Explorer (say `\\NAS`, from a computer on the same domain). A popup appears that asks for my credentials and says "*The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Try again later*". Entering the crendentials is of no use.
- Accessing the shared folders with the IP address seems to be working (say `\\192.168.1.50`, from a computer on the same domain).
- From the domain controller, accessing the shared folders with the network name seems to be working, though very slowly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in DNS. What does the name resolve to, if anything?

Comment: DNS resolves to the right (and same) IP address...

Answer (score 1):

First, open command prompt and type:

```
ping nas
```

If that does not return the correct IP address, then you have a DNS problem.  I suggest you flush your dns cache first - from a command prompt (as administrator) type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then try to access the nas again.  If this doesn't work and the ping is still returning the wrong IP then check your domain controller, where I assume your DNS is hosted on (if you are using Windows Server, then this is mostly like the server it resides on).  Make sure you don't have multiple records for NAS which would create a round-robin type of dns record and give you the wrong IP about half of the time.  You can manually change that DNS record in Windows if it is wrong... Also check the IP settings on that computer that won't resolve the address and make sure your DNS server is correct (usually that Windows server).  Clear your DNS cache again (above) and try it again.

Comment: Thanks, but the DNS seems to be fine...

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was to go control panel > users > manage credentials. For some reason there as a credential for my Nas there. After I removed it everything worked.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why this approach addresses the scenario described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if go to Control Panel > Directory Service got to Domain Users - do a search for the problematic user. Double click the users & select Red/Write on the share you need to give them access to.